Custom Shape in Flutter in BottomSheet
I am working on a Flutter project and need help creating a custom shape for a BottomSheet. I have tried multiple approaches with CustomPainter and Clipper, but I haven't been able to achieve the exact shape I want. Below is the image of the shape I need to create:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, -size.height, size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}


Share the image that you want to create.

https://i.sstatic.net/4Bb82KLj.png

@DroidFlutter i have attached image url

Try below code without CustomPainter...
 showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(15))),
                    child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(-150, -250),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100,
                            height: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 80,
                              height: 80,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  );
                },
              );

Apply Offset as your requirement
